# Linear transformation of simply connected set: is it simply connected?

Tags: algebraic-topology, linear-transformations

Let $S$ be a topological space that embedds in some normed space $V$. Let $W$ be another normed space, with $\text{dim}(W)<\infty$. Let $L:V\to W$ be a linear map.

Assume that $S$ is simply connected. Does it follow that $L(S)$ is also simply connected?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933): show your attempts.

Comment: Got it, I'll do my best. On my side: please be more polite to newcomers. As you see, the question was answered with a perfectly fitting and comprehensive answer. Flagging it as "not meeting the MSE guidelines" was a bit rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normed space stuff is just a distraction. The universal covering of $S^1$ can already be described as the restriction of the (continuous!) linear map $$L:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^2\\ L(x,y,z)=(x,y)$$
to the subset $S=\{(\cos\theta,\sin\theta,\theta)\,:\, \theta\in\Bbb R\}\cong \Bbb R$. If you want something in infinite dimension, consider $\tilde L:\Bbb R^3\times\ell^2\to \Bbb R^2$, $\tilde L(x,y,z,f)=(x,y)$ and $\tilde S=S\times\ell^2$.

Comment: Thanks, you are totally right!

Comment: This is ridiculous. From to the quality standard policy:

- Title and tags [seems ok]
- Formatting, writing, notation [seems ok]
- Pare question to its basics [ok]
- Math contests [unrelated]
- Check similar questions first [done]
- 1 question per post [ok]
- Context [questionable].

Thus, your only concern is "context", which, in my opinion, is fundamental for highly specific questions, but not quite so when it comes to basic undergraduate stuff. Rules are very useful, but sticking rigidly to them without further thoughts is unprofessional. Thanks again Giulio for your clear answer.